# form posting to database

Tags: php, database, forms

I have created a form and I'm trying to post data to MySQL databasem, but after submitting the form i am getting the following error..

> Notice: Undefined index: month in C:\xampp\htdocs\auto\insert_ac.php on line 14
>   Notice: Undefined index: listner_name in C:\xampp\htdocs\auto\insert_ac.php on line 15
>   Notice: Undefined index: rj_name in C:\xampp\htdocs\auto\insert_ac.php on line 16
>   Notice: Undefined index: channel in C:\xampp\htdocs\auto\insert_ac.php on line 17
>   Notice: Undefined index: year in C:\xampp\htdocs\auto\insert_ac.php on line 18
>   Notice: Undefined index: country in C:\xampp\htdocs\auto\insert_ac.php on line 19

When i check a blank row entry inserted in to my database

```
<?php

$host="localhost"; // Host name
$username="root"; // Mysql username`
$password=""; // Mysql password
$db_name="auto"; // Database name
$tbl_name="song_request"; // Table name

// Connect to server and select database.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// Get values from form
$month=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['month']);
$listner_name=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['listner_name']);
$rj_name=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['rj_name']);
$channel=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['channel']);
$year=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['year']);
$country=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['country']);

// Insert data into mysql

$sql="INSERT INTO song_request (month, listner_name, rj_name, channel, year, country)VALUES('$month', '$listner_name', '$rj_name', '$channel', '$year', '$country')";
$result=mysql_query($sql) or die ('error Updating database');

// if successfully insert data into database, displays message "Successful".
if($result){
echo "Successful";
echo "<BR>";
echo "<a href='index.html'>Back to main page</a>";
}

else {
echo "ERROR";
}

// close connection
mysql_close();
?>
```

My HTML form code is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>Radio Mantra Song Request</title>
  <link href="css/jquery.autocomplete.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.5.2.min.js">
</script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.autocomplete.pack.js">
</script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js">
</script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <form name="form" method="post" action="insert_ac.php">
      <p><label>Location:</label> <input id="month" type="text" autocomplete="off"></p>

      <p><label>Listner Name:</label> <input id="listner_name" type="text" autocomplete=
      "off"></p>

      <p><label>RJ Name:</label> <input id="rj_name" type="text" autocomplete="off"></p>

      <p><label>Channel:</label> <input id="channel" type="text" autocomplete="off"></p>

      <p><label>Show Name:</label> <input id="year" type="text" autocomplete="off"></p>

      <p><label>Song:</label> <input id="country" type="text" autocomplete="off"></p>

      <h2>Radio Mantra</h2>

      <table>
        <tr>
          <td align="center"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to using a `name` attribute as pointed out by SeanNieuwoudt, you should probably also check that the request method is `POST` before inserting into the database. If you don't do that and someone decides to view your insert_ac.php page as a GET request, it will generate the same notices as before and insert blank data.

For example

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
    // go ahead and insert
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You need a **name** attribute on your form elements in order to access the values in $_POST.

```
 <input id="month" name="month" type="text" autocomplete="off">
```

Comment: Thanks it's works.. :) one more thing.. how can i restrict blank entries in to database.

Answer (score 0):

you should have a name attribute in your form elements.

you got this error may because the values are not populated.

```
Notice: Undefined index: month in C:\xampp\htdocs\auto\insert_ac.php on line 14
Notice: Undefined index: listner_name in C:\xampp\htdocs\auto\insert_ac.php on line 15
Notice: Undefined index: rj_name in C:\xampp\htdocs\auto\insert_ac.php on line 16
Notice: Undefined index: channel in C:\xampp\htdocs\auto\insert_ac.php on line 17
Notice: Undefined index: year in C:\xampp\htdocs\auto\insert_ac.php on line 18
Notice: Undefined index: country in C:\xampp\htdocs\auto\insert_ac.php on line 19
```

if you have something like `$_POST["test"]`, you have to check whether such index exists by doing this:

```
if(isset($_POST["test"]))
```

so just use like the following

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$month=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['month']);
$listner_name=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['listner_name']);
$rj_name=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['rj_name']);
$channel=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['channel']);
$year=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['year']);
$country=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['country']);

// Insert data into mysql

$sql="INSERT INTO song_request (month, listner_name, rj_name, channel, year, country)VALUES('$month', '$listner_name', '$rj_name', '$channel', '$year', '$country')";
$result=mysql_query($sql) or die ('error Updating database');
}
```